# Focusing on TextInput on focus react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an OTP screen, I've added a ref to the first `TextInput` field so that when the screen loads, it gets focused:

```
// ref
const pin1 = useRef();

// navigation listener
navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
     pin1.current.focus();
})
```

But it returns an error:
`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'pin1.current.focus')`

This code works pretty well:

```
navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
     alert('Hello')
})
```

Comment: have you passed that ref as props to TextInput ?

Comment: @TusharPandey yes

Comment: can you please share your code or more sections related to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `autoFocus={true}` with your TextInput you when you open the screen your TextInput automatically focused.

Check [autoFocus](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#autofocus)

Comment: Short and sweet. Thank you for this.

Comment: The simple answers are always the best

Answer (score 1):

You should check the **current** object before calling any function.

```
navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      if (pin1.current) {
        pin1.current.focus();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Embed the listener inside a `useEffect`

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
        pin1.current.focus();
     })
    }
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation, pin1]);
```

also

```js
<TextInput ref={pin1} />
```